# Undefined variable (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Why I get this error?

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: users (View:
>   /Users/acny/Desktop/Actor/resources/views/home.blade.php)

function of controller :

```
public function getData()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('home', compact('users'));
    }
```

and .blade :

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user }}
 @endforeach
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: before return view  write dd($users) and check if $users exist or not

Comment: Need more info for better clarity.

Comment: I think it is because, You've sent the users data to the the "index.blade.php" view and you are using it in the "home.blade.php".

Comment: I fixed it but still get this error

Comment: Show me your index.blade.php and home.blade.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error from `home.blade.php`, but `getData()` try to load in`user/index.blade.php`.

Are you sure your request going through method `getData()`?

Comment: You are right ! I fixed it but still get this error ! What should I do to make the get() method work properly?

Comment: Can i see web.php?

Comment: Please look the above code again. I fixed it but still not working!

Answer (score 0):

web.php :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); });

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Here is your problem :) Add `Route::get('/link-to-your-page', 'HomeController@getData');`. More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: My problem solved. I write new route with new view for UserController